# How do you setup multiple jest configs within a single project?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

In the `create-react-app` boilerplate it has both server and client code using the same `package.json` file.  I'd like to have three separate jest configs: client unit tests, server unit tests, and server integration tests.  Unfortunately, I haven't been able to get this to work.  My plan was to have `yarn run` commands for each option and then specify the config to jest using the `--config` CLI option.  But then I ran into [this roadblock](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/3584) which happens on both v20 and v21 and is showing no progress.   Basically, people are reporting issues with reading config files using `--config` and the fallback is to use the config `package.json`.  Unfortunately, you can only specify a single config file.

Has anyone managed to get this to work and if so can you describe your setup (the version of jest, etc).  I'm wondering if I need to downgrade to v19.  Alternatively, am I just taking the wrong approach?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Apparently the up and coming feature of jest is the `--projects` option.  You can do something like this in your package.json file:

```
"jest": {
  "projects": [
    "src/client/jest.config.js",
    "src/server/unit.jest.config.js",
    "src/server/int.jest.config.js",
   ]
}
```

And then in `src/client/jest.config.js` you can define a specific configuration:

```
module.exports = {
  name: 'client',
  displayName: 'client',

  // NOTE: if you don't set this correctly then when you reference
  // it later in a path string you'll get a confusing error message.
  // It says something like' Module <rootDir>/config/polyfills.js in
  // the setupFiles option was not found.'
  rootDir: './../../',

  testMatch: [
    "<rootDir>/src/server/**/__tests__/*.unit.{js,jsx}",
    "<rootDir>/src/server/**/__tests__/unit/*.{js,jsx}"
  ],

  // etc...
};
```

Here's the post describing the feature: 
https://facebook.github.io/jest/blog/2017/05/06/jest-20-delightful-testing-multi-project-runner.html

Answer (score 2):

I had a very similar issue. I wanted to run a lightweight jest locally when developing but a heavier, with test coverage, in the pipeline.

The solution I found was to pass a flag into the config.

in the `package.json`

```
{
  "name": "project",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "cross-env DEV=false jest --maxWorkers=30% ",
    "test:coverage": "cross-env DEV=true jest --collectCoverage"
  }
}
```

Then in the `jest.config.js` file

```
module.exports = () => {
  // only collect cover if true
  const isDev = process.env.DEV === 'true';
  
  return {
    "collectCoverage": isDev ? false : true,
    "collectCoverageFrom": [
      "src/**/*.{js,ts, tsx}"
    ],
    "coverageDirectory": "coverage",
    "roots": [
      "<rootDir>/src"
      ]
  };
};
```

Now you will have the ability to change the config, but use the same file for all setups.